# Show that there doesn't exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$.

Tags: functional-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Show that there doesn't exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ that converges pointwise to $f$ such that

$\forall x\in\Bbb{Q} \space f(x)=1$ and $\forall x\notin\Bbb{Q} \space f(x)=0$.

I know how to prove this using Baire's Category Theorem but I am not allowed to use it in this particular course. Is there proof of this that would not utilize BCT and the likes of it?

Comment: did you mean for all $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ that $f(x) \neq 1$ instead?

Comment: @devianceee Even more specific, they should be equal to 0 :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think the jump from any proof I know to the Baire category theorem is fairly simple (mostly simple generalizations), so it is not clear to me what this exercise is intended to accomplish. That said, maybe [Volterra's original proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=Volterra+%22baire+category%22) will work. For example, see [*No functions continuous only at points in a countable dense set*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06453) by Silva/Wu, or see Section 1.4 (pp. 10-14) in Frank A. Ballone's Masters thesis [**On Volterra Spaces**](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=ysu1288364649).

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice it before, but your function is **nowhere continuous**, and perhaps a simpler argument will work in that case. However, I don't have time right now to dig into this issue any more, but I suspect the links I gave earlier will give any such simpler argument if any are reasonably well known.

Answer (score 2):

A measure-theoretic proof: Suppose that $f_n\to f$ pointwise and that all $f_n$ are continuous. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, small. Then since $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[-N,N]$, by [Egorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem), there exists a Lebesgue-measurable subset $E\subset[-N,N]$ such that $m([-N,N]\setminus E)<\varepsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$. But then $f$ has to be continuous on $E$, which is impossible, since $f$ is continuous nowhere.

Comment: Great use of Egorov's theorem! +1

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Thank you:)

Comment: No problem! And also, doesn't your proof generalize to include any function $f$ that is nowhere continuous? Not just the $f$ stated in the OP's post.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts It generalizes even more for any function that is discontinuous on a set of positive measure

Comment: Right, because then we can take finite measured subsets and apply Egorov's on those

Comment: @NicholasRoberts exactly

Comment: Sorry, just one more clarification: when you say discontinuous on a set of positive measure, you mean that there is at least one point in that set where the function is discontinuous? And under this relaxed condition on the function $f$, the statement still holds?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I mean that the set of points where if is not continuous is of positive measure. With this hypothesis the same technique works

Comment: going through the proofs of everything, I'd say this is the measure theoretic analogue of the Baire Category Theorem argument

Comment: @mathworker21 I totally agree